# Why do my touch event not work?

Tags: objective-c

I have declared a void touchesbegan method in my controller but it doesn't work! i don't know why. i have an image view which i plan to click it to move to next controller. so i set the touches began method. i have linked the image view in the xib file but when i click the image. nothing happens. Please help, Thanks.

### ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface imageViewViewController : UIViewController
{
    IBOutlet UIImageView *testing;
}
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *testing;

@end
```

### ViewController.m

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    if(touch.view == testing)
    {
        TestViewController *testviewcontroller = [[TestViewController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:testviewcontroller animated:YES];
    }
}

@end
```

P.S.

here i tried another method using tap gestures. 
testing is the name of my image view. as u can see i comment out the ns log in the imagedidtapped method. it works til that point. however when i tried to navigate it out to another page it fails.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{


    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer;
    [testing setTag:0]; 
    [testing setUserInteractionEnabled:TRUE];
    tapRecognizer = [[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imageViewDidTapped:)] autorelease];
    tapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [testing addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
    [self.view addSubview:testing];
    [testing release];





    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}



- (void)imageViewDidTapped:(UIGestureRecognizer *)aGesture {
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = (UITapGestureRecognizer *)aGesture;

   UIImageView *tappedImageView = (UIImageView *)[tapGesture view];

    switch (tappedImageView.tag) {
        case 0:
            //NSLog(@"UIImageView 1 was tapped");
            [self navigate];

            break;
        case 1:
            NSLog(@"UIImageView 2 was tapped");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}



-(void)navigate
{
    TestViewController *testviewcontroller = [[TestViewController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:testviewcontroller animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `testing` is connected to the image view in your xib or storyboard?

Comment: What means "when i click the image. nothing happens"? Is touchesBegan:withEvent: not called at all, or is pushViewController:animated: not called?

Comment: the touches began is called. However it just doesn't navigate to another views controller. i had set the animated to yes. nothing happens.

Comment: you keep changing your story about what exactly is the problem you want help with: is it touch handling or is it navigation in a UINavigationController? Try to get clear in your own mind and ask your question clearly.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that by default `userInteractionEnabled` is NO for a UIImageView so you won't get any touches. Set it to YES.

Also the message handling for `touchesBegan` is really complicated. You'll be much happier if you attach a UITapGestureRecognizer to the image view.

EDIT: Now you say your touches handling *is* working, but the navigation is not taking place. So let's concentrate on this part of your code:

```
-(void)navigate
{
    TestViewController *testviewcontroller = [[TestViewController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:testviewcontroller animated:YES];
}
```

Put logging in there to make sure `navigate` is being called! If it isn't being called, you need to figure out why your other code is not running and calling it. If it *is* being called, then the problem is probably that `self.navigationController` is nil, i.e. you are not inside a navigation interface to start with.

Comment: yes i already set the user interaction to a yes but it still doesn't work.

Comment: hi matt. i tried using tap gestures. i edited my codes above. please help me take a look. it just doesn't work when i tries to navigate it out of my view controller. Thanks

Comment: see edits; it is unclear what problem you are actually having